# hope css code inject into html <style> when use vite build vue3 app

Tags: css, vue.js, build, vite, inject

I use vite to build the vue3 app with an index.html, I hope the output HTML can contain the CSS code in the  tab in the HTML file, rather than a CSS file `<link>` in it.

what should I do?

`App.vue` file code:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import './app.css';

const count = ref(0);

function addCount() {
  count.value++;
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="addCount">{{ count }}</button>
  <div class="good">good</div>
  <img src="./20230707075538555-900x900.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
</template>

<style scoped>
.good {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

I use createSSRApp to create the app.

`index.html` is  simple

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <!--preload-links-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"><!--app-html--></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/entry-client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use vite to build, config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"; //add this line

export default defineConfig({
    base: '/',
    build: {
      cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
    plugins: [
      vue(), // write this
    ],
});
```

finally, the output file code is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <!--preload-links-->
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-d8e5f2e3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style-fac1f9f2.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"><!--app-html--></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope it can replace the CSS  with the  tab containing CSS code.

I try importing separate CSS files in the `<style scope>` tab in the vue file or importing CSS files in the script. It didn't work.

and I try use this plugin in vite config:

```
import { libInjectCss } from 'vite-plugin-lib-inject-css';
```

bug it to throw an error during the build process。

error during build:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Comment: Can you add full error message or provide a minimal reproduction for this?